# Check Cookies AND Session in Same IF Statement

Tags: asp.net, session, if-statement, cookies

I have a function that checks for Session and Cookies and redirects user based on those.

```
private void CheckRecruiterLogin()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        if (Session["Candidate"] != null ||
            Request.Cookies["Candidate"] != null)
        {
            list = (List<string>)Session["Candidate"];
            string status = list[1].ToString();
            if (status.Equals("applicant") ||
                Request.Cookies["Candidate"]["Status"].Equals("applicant"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("ApplicantHome.aspx");
            }
            if (status.Equals("preboarding") ||
                Request.Cookies["Candidate"]["Status"].Equals("preboarding"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("PreboardingHome.aspx");
            }
            else if (status.Equals("hiring") ||
                Request.Cookies["Candidate"]["Status"].Equals("hiring"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("HiringHome.aspx");
            }
        }
        else if (Session["HR"] != null || Request.Cookies["HR"] != null)
        {
            list = (List<string>)Session["HR"];
            string type = list[1].ToString();
            if (type.Equals("preboarder") ||
                Request.Cookies["HR"]["Type"].Equals("preboarder"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("PreboarderList.aspx");
            }
            else if (type.Equals("datamanager") ||
                Request.Cookies["HR"]["Type"].Equals("datamanager"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("HiringList.aspx");
            }
            else if (type.Equals("admin") ||
                Request.Cookies["HR"]["Type"].Equals("admin"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("AdminHome.aspx");
            }
        }
        else if (Session["HR"] == null &&
            Request.Cookies["HR"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
        }
    }
```

But the application throws a runtime exception saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I believe this is because there are no cookies present.

My question is: Should I separate the checking of sessions and cookies, or can I do it in one statement?

Thanks!

Comment: first put a break-point over there and try to figure it out that where the exception is thrown and why ?

Comment: @Anjush Jain Like I said, the error is in the Cookie checking, because there are no cookies present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code requires *both* the cookie, and the session.

If this is intended, you want to change the condition to use `&&` instead of `||`.

However, it's more likely you intend the code to use session if available, and cookies if session isn't there. This is quite simply done by storing the value in a variable, and using that later:

```
if (Session["Candidate"] != null || Request.Cookies["Candidate"] != null)
{
  var list = Session["Candidate"] as List<string>;
  var status = list == null ? Request.Cookies["Candidate"]["Status"] : list[1];

  if (status == "applicant")
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

That said, using cookies for security checks like this is a bad idea - they are user visible and user editable.

Also, there's no point in using `Equals` - just use `==`. This isn't Java, .NET actually compares the value, not the reference. Although it's probably a better idea to actually do the comparison using invariant culture, case insensitive equality. There's also no point in creating `new List<string>` - the value is never used. Just declare the variable at the point where you already have something to fill it with.

Comment: I want my code to check for cookies or session. I am just not sure if I should do it in the same if statement.

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño Use my code then. The basic approach is to simply take the value (from either session or cookie, based on availability), and only use that variable from then on. This makes it easy and readable to use. Although I'd far more prefer turning `Candidate` into a property (separating the session / cookie properties or not, depending on your requirements). Then you could just do `var status = Candidate;` or `var status = SessionData.Candidate ?? CookieData.Candidate;` or something like that.

Comment: I want to know what this line does `var status = list == null ? Request.Cookies["Candidate"]["Status"] : list[1];` I'm guessing that this line sets the value of status based on the availability of cookie or session.

Comment: @Luann I'll try and figure out the syntax in that line; this is somewhat new to me. `var status = list[1]` unless there is a cookie. If there is, `var status = Request.Cookies["Candidate"]["Status"]`. Is this correct? I don't understand the `var status = list == null` part.

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño Yeah, it's called the ternary operator - it's basically an if-then-else statement as a single expression: `condition ? whatToReturnIfConditionIsTrue : whatToReturnIfConditionIsFalse`.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly checking that if `Request` has a cookie named "**HR**" which will throw exception if there is no cookie with this name. So you first need to check if `CookieCollection` have any cookie with name "**HR**". Here is method which checks if `CookieCollection` have a cookie with a given name.

```
if(Request.Cookies.Get("cookieNmae") !=null)
```

So change your if statement like this

```
if (Session["HR"] != null || Request.Cookies.Get("HR") !=null)
```

Comment: Have you changed this in every condition where you are checking this ?

Comment: its working for me even i haven't used any sessions or cookies i am not getting any exception `if (Request.Cookies.Get("some") != null || Session["mairaj"]!=null)`

Comment: You have 3 conditions have you changed in all 3 ?

Comment: Also you are checking cookies within the conditions which means you will get inside the if condition even cookie is null but session is not null so you should either put `&&` condition or you should check in two different conditions one for session one for cookies.

Comment: Yes, all statements changed. I am not sure if it still works when I'm getting the key: `if (type.Equals("preboarder") || Request.Cookies.Get("HR")["Type"].Equals("preboarder"))`

Comment: So are you suggesting I should separate the checking for sessions and cookies into two functions, instead of doing it all in one statement with `||`?

Comment: Yes you should because if one thing is NUll you will get exception so you should check if Session is not null do all processing from Session and if cookie is not null do all processing from Cookie.